# .transition modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want the second rectangle (green) come up and down over the first rectangle (red) when I press the button

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var visible = false

    var body: some View {
        return HStack {
            Button("button") {
                self.visible.toggle()
            }
            ZStack {

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)

                if visible {   
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .animation(.linear(duration: 2))
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the green rectangle appears it comes up over the red rectangle, but when it disappears the the moving transition appears behind the red rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `zIndex`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var visible = false

    var body: some View {
        return HStack {
            Button("button") {
                self.visible.toggle()
            }
            ZStack {

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)

                if visible {   
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .animation(.linear(duration: 2))
                        .zIndex(1)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```